# Select data with conditional rules (count) from other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I had these structure in my DB :

```
Table coupon
coupon_id , code, max_used

Table coupon_history
coupon_history_id, coupon_id, used_date
```

Can I get coupon data where "coupon.max_used" no more than total history at "coupon_history"?
I get stuck here. I need to get a coupon_code. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `JOIN` and `IN` like this:

```
SELECT cc.* FROM coupon cc
WHERE cc.coupon_id IN
  (
    SELECT c.coupon_id FROM Coupon c
    LEFT JOIN
    (  SELECT coupon_id, COUNT(coupon_id) maxUsed
         FROM coupon_history GROUP BY coupon_id
    ) ch 
    ON c.Coupon_id = ch.Coupon_id
    WHERE c.max_used > ch.maxUsed
       OR ch.maxUsed IS NULL
  );
```

Or you can simply use `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT cc.* FROM coupon cc
JOIN 
  (
    SELECT c.coupon_id FROM Coupon c
    LEFT JOIN
    (  SELECT coupon_id, COUNT(coupon_id) maxUsed
         FROM coupon_history GROUP BY coupon_id
    ) ch 
    ON c.Coupon_id = ch.Coupon_id
    WHERE c.max_used > ch.maxUsed
       OR ch.maxUsed IS NULL
  ) c ON cc.coupon_id = c.coupon_id;
```

#### Have a look at [this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5d0d/13)

---

**Edit**: about your [second requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483747/select-data-with-conditional-rules-count-from-other-table/17484238#comment-25411869)

Try this query:

```
SELECT cc.*,c.TotalUsed FROM coupon cc
JOIN 
  (
    SELECT c.coupon_id,TotalUsed FROM Coupon c
    LEFT JOIN
    (  SELECT coupon_id, COUNT(coupon_id) TotalUsed
         FROM coupon_history GROUP BY coupon_id
    ) ch 
    ON c.Coupon_id = ch.Coupon_id
    WHERE c.max_used > ch.TotalUsed
       OR ch.TotalUsed IS NULL
  ) c ON cc.coupon_id = c.coupon_id;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5d0d/30)

Comment: great answer!!.. but how can I show how many that coupon used at the same query?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below:

```
select IF(count(*)<max_used,'less','more') as T,coupon.* 
          from coupon
 LEFT JOIN  coupon_history ON coupon_history.coupon_id = coupon.coupon_id
  group by coupon_history.coupon_id
```

You can check the 'status' for each row to know it is more than max_used or not. Just a different approach.

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5d0d/25

Comment: great solution, but what is 'less' and 'more' state mean?
how can I show how many that coupon used at the same query?

Comment: Less means max_used is less than coupon_history count and More means coupon_history count exceeds max_used.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to see COUNT formula. Thanks.
both of you and @hims056 was give me a correct answer.

Comment: can you help me again?? your query only show coupon that already used once, but it wont return any voucher that never used. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution here, but I hope there's more suggestion about other query, because I dont test the efficiency and effectiveness.

Here's :

```
SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE coupon_id = 'MY_COUPON_ID' AND 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coupon_history) < max_used
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select coupon.* from coupon
join 
(
  select coupon_id, count(*) Count_Coupons_History 
     from coupon_history 
  group by coupon_id
) t on (coupon.coupon_id=t.coupon_id) 
       and (coupon.max_used<=t.Count_Coupons_History)
```